# Fetching entire changelog for an issue in JIRA using jira-python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

Using jira-python, I want to retrieve the entire changelog for a JIRA issue:

```
issues_returned = jira.search_issues(args.jql, expand='changelog')
```

I discovered that for issues with more than 100 entries in their changelog I am only receiving the first 100:

[image: Screenshot from debugger]

My question is how do I specify a startAt and make another call to get subsequent pages of the changelog (using python-jira)?

From [this thread at Atlassian](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Rest-API-limiting-changelog-history-results-to-100-even-if/qaq-p/1466525) I see that API v3 provides an endpoint to get the change log directly:

```
/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/changelog
```

but this doesn't seem to be accessible via jira-python.  I'd like to avoid having to do the REST call directly and authenticate separately.  Barring a way to do it directly via jira-python, is there a way to make a 'raw' REST API call from jira-python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In instances where more than 100 results are present, you'll need to edit the 'startAt' parameter when searching issues:

```
issues_returned = jira.search_issues(args.jql, expand='changelog', startAt=100)
```

You'll need to setup a statement that compares the 'total' and 'maxResults' data points, then run another query with a different 'startAt' parameter if the total is higher and append the two together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the package / API got changed since the accepted answer, but it is not true anymore. I tested it today:

The `startAt` parameter only relates to the offset concerning the number of issues, *not the changelog*.

On a positive note, with `expand=["changelog"]` enabled the request seemingly  **returns all the changes at once for an issue** anyway. I was able to test this with a changelog of **34.822 changes**.

The parameter `startAt` has no influence on the number or offset of items in the changelog.