# Getting detailed data on JIRA status changes using the JIRA python library

Tags: jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm trying to use [python library](https://jira.readthedocs.io/index.html) to get the date/time of each transition TO and FROM status in a JIRA ticket.

According to the documentation, the transitions object is responsible for this.
I'm use

```
transitions = jira.transitions('BO-623', expand="changelog")
for v in transitions:
    print(v)
```

but i get answer from script without any information about previous status of transition and without date/time of transition:

```
{'id': '31', 'name': 'To Do', 'to': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/status/10007', 'description': '', 'iconUrl': 'https://my.jira.server.com/images/icons/statuses/open.png', 'name': 'To Do', 'id': '10007', 'statusCategory': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2', 'id': 2, 'key': 'new', 'colorName': 'blue-gray', 'name': 'To Do'}}}
{'id': '51', 'name': 'Done', 'to': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/status/10005', 'description': 'Status indicates that this task has been completed..', 'iconUrl': 'https://my.jira.server.com/images/icons/statuses/closed.png', 'name': 'Done', 'id': '10005', 'statusCategory': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3', 'id': 3, 'key': 'done', 'colorName': 'green', 'name': 'Done'}}}
```

Help me please to find solution - How i can get date/time of each transition TO and FROM status in a JIRA ticket using [python library](https://jira.readthedocs.io/index.html)?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379061/fetching-entire-changelog-for-an-issue-in-jira-using-jira-python